# How can I use Google App Engine Url Fetch to get google play book description

Tags: google-app-engine, http-request, google-books

I am using google app engine's urlfetch sevice to get book description from google play. When I fetch the url

https://play.google.com/store/books

, I can get correct web page html content and parse it in my local developement enviroment. But on production server, Google Play just give me a "Unavailable in your country" page.

This is my test code referenced from GAE document(https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet)

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://play.google.com/store/books");
    final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    // connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US");
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       log.warn(line);
    }
    reader.close();    
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
```

I also try to change request property "Accept-Language" but not work. Do you have any ideas for this ?

Comment: and where are you, if I may ask? there has been issues with my app and certain countries where it was basically Google enforcing different US restrictions that just could not be bypassed :(

Comment: I am from Aisa. I also try to find if there is any setup I can do to change data center of my GAE application, but not work. I wonder how Facebook can do the job perfectly?

Comment: Nah, unless you enable a "EU" app, there is no way to control where your app will land. I had an issue with my app and certain chinese customers. In that case, the problem was unsolvable : google is NOT ALLOWED to "serve" certain physical locations from their USA datacenters.  If you enable a Europe app, you might have better luck :(